# Having trouble with Oauth2 and Postman

Tags: imgur

I am attempting to use postman with imgur api I used the 'open with postman' button at the top of the documentation page and tried to obtain a token with the default populated settings for callback authorization and token url's and I get a popup window with:

{"data":{"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch","request":"/oauth2/authorize","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":400}

I am hoping this is a simple thing as i am pretty new to api's.

`Further info:

```
callback url: https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback,

auth url: https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize,  

Access Token url: https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token,

no Scope,   

no State ,  

Client authentication: send as basic header
```

`

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem but I fixed it.

See if your callback URL in Postman is the same as your Redirect in Imgur (You can always edit it in Imgur) https://imgur.com/account/settings/apps.
Also, make sure that there is no comma at the end in the callback URL in Postman (That was my mistake). Everything else looks fine but just in case I'll show you what I have.

```
Postman:
Get -> https://api.imgur.com/3/account/me/images

Callback URL: https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
Auth URL: https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize
Access Token URL: https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token
Scope, State: Empty
Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth header
```

Comment: by default callback url is https://imgur.com